# Indexing Dictionary in a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following problem:

Given a dictionary in dictionary:

```
dict1={"user1":{"id":"1", "link":"http://..."}, "user2":{"id":"2", "link":"http://..."}, ... }
```

I need:

```
params = {"user_ids":["1","2", ... ]}
```

I tried:

```
params ={
    "user_ids": dict1.values()["id"]
}
```

but that's not working. It gives an error: `'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Loop over the dict and grab the id value from each of the dict's internal dictionaries...

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[d['id'] for d in dict1.values()]`

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension:

```
user_ids = [d['id'] for d in dict1.values()]
```

Or using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

user_ids = list(map(itemgetter('id'), dict1.values()))
```

Comment: You can use itemgetter in a comprehension just fine

Comment: Correct, although it's not usually the way I use `itemgetter`. The comprehension is faster though so I swapped them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop. Loop using for loop and each one will be inner dict. Now append all the "ids" in a list. After completion of loop, create a dictionary and print it. Your code:

```
dict1={"user1":{"id":"1", "link":"http://..."}, "user2":{"id":"2", "link":"http://..."} }
f=[]
for i in dict1:
    f.append(dict1[i]["id"])
f1={"user_ids":f}
print(f1)
```

Edit you dict1 accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then the question is that the keys are in the form user + digit, then:

```
dict1 = {"user1":{"id":"1", "link":"http://..."}, "user2":{"id":"2", "link":"http://..."}}

ids = []

for k, v in dict1.items():
    if 'user' in k:
        for k, v in v.items():
            if k == 'id':
                ids.append(v)

params = {'users_id': ids}
print(params)
```

result: {'users_id': ['1', '2']}